# Apache2 403 permission denied on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a sub-directory in my /var/www folder called prod, which is password protected. It was all working fine until I asked my server admin to help me set up allow all access to one particular file. Now the entire folder is just giving me a 403 error. This is the sites-enabled file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.co.uk
  # Server name
  ServerName prod.xxx.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/prod
  <Directory /var/www/prod>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please log in"
    AuthUserFile /home/ubuntu/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/prod/xxx/cgi-bin/api.pl>
   Allow from All
   Satisfy Any
 </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /xxx/cgi-bin/ /var/www/prod/xxx/cgi-bin/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prod.xxx.error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prod.xxx.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now he's unsure why this is blocking me out completely. No permissions have been changed, but this is the /var/www/ folder:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root     4096 Jan  3 21:10 images
4 drwxr-sr-x  4 root    www-data 4096 Mar 31 14:47 jslib
4 drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root     4096 Jun  2 13:00 prod
```

When I try to visit http://prod.xxx.co.uk, I don't get asked for the password; I just get 403'd

I hope I've given enough information...

Anyone able to spot something he can't?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing:

```
allow from all
```

from the Directory for prod